# How to update a dict value with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
sample_dict = {
      "matchings": [
        {
          "indices": [
            0,
            1,
            2
          ],
          "geometry": "hemo_Ab}gueC????",
          "matched_points": [
            [
              -33.823845,
              -70.619614
            ],
            [
              -33.823845,
              -70.619614
            ],
            [
              -33.823845,
              -70.619614
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I update the geometry value?

Comment: `sample_json["matchings"][0]["geometry"] = "whatever"`

Comment: is this a .json file or a .py file?

Comment: What if the item number is unknown? How would I loop through it?

Comment: Then it's not a "json", it's a Python `dict`

Comment: Thanks Jivan. I created the dict from a json. You are right, now it is a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through your `matchings` with this syntax:

```
for i, matching in enumerate(sample_json['matchings']):
    # i is your matching's index
    # matching is your current matching object
    my_new_value = 'something'
    sample_json["matchings"][i]["geometry"] = my_new_value
```